# Ionic / Angular update scope on page transition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

I'm creating an application using the Ionic framework. I have one view with a controller that looks something like this

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, service) { //Controller for app.main

    $scope.main = service.data;
})
```

A user can go to a sub page from this main page, and further manipulate `service.data`.

```
.controller('MainSubCtrl', function ($scope, service) {
    service.data = 'do something';
    $scope.goBack = function ()
    {
        $state.go('app.main');
    }
})
```

When they are done, `$scope.goBack` takes them back.

How can I ensure that $scope.main is updated when the view transitions?

Comment: You can use options to reload state even if no changes occured: $state.go("app.main", {}, {reload: true});

Comment: I've tried using that parameter without success. I looked on github and it looks like there is a bug, but I don't know if it's influencing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can $watch your change in a function

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, service) { //Controller for app.main
    $scope.$watch(function() {
         return service.data;
    },
    function(newval, oldval) {
         $scope.main = newval;
    }
});
```